# Rails 5 grouping by belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a `sale_selection` model which belongs_to both `purchase` and `sale`.

In a Postgres query i'm trying to search by some params, grouping the sale `item_name` and then getting the average price.

I'm getting the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "sale"
```

**Controller**

```
@search = Purchase.where('extract(year from sale_year) >= ?', params[:select_year])
.joins(:region).where('regions.name = ?', params[:select_region])
.joins(sale_selections: :sale).group('sale.item_name').select('sale.item_name, AVG(sale.price) as price')
```

Comment: Can you please add model associations in question ?

Comment: There is typo mistake in `group` and `select` query in third  row, write `sales` instead of `sale`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correction in table name provided in query is needed (`sales` instead of `sale`) as below,

```
@search = Purchase.where('extract(year from sale_year) >= ?', params[:select_year])
.joins(:region).where('regions.name = ?', params[:select_region])
.joins(sale_selections: :sale).group('sales.item_name').select('sales.item_name, AVG(sales.price) as price')
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are following rails best practices table name should be `sales` instead of `sale`

```
@search = Purchase.where('extract(year from sale_year) >= ?', params[:select_year])
.joins(:region).where('regions.name = ?', params[:select_region])
.joins(sale_selections: :sale).group('sales.item_name').select('sales.item_name, AVG(sales.price) as price')
```